# How to use VI to remove ocurance of character on lines matching regex?

Tags: regex, vim, replace, vi

I'm trying to change the case of method names for some functions from `lowercase_with_underscores` to `lowerCamelCase` for lines that begin with `public function get_method_name()`. I'm struggling to get this done in a single step.

So far I have used the following

```
:%s/\(get\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)_\(\w\)/\1\2\u\3/g
```

However, this only replaces one `_` character at a time. What I would like it a search and replace that does something like the following:

1. Identify all lines containing the string `public function [gs]et`.
2. On these lines, perform the following search and replace `:s/_\(\w\)/\u\1/g`
   (

EDIT:

Suppose I have lines `get_method_name()` and `set_method_name($variable_name)` and I only want to change the case of the method name and not the variable name, how might I do that? The `get_method_name()` is more simple of course, but I'd like a solution that works for both in a single command. I've been able to use `:%g/public function [gs]et/ . . .` as per the solution listed below to solve for the `get_method_name()` case, but unfortunately not the `set_method_name($variable_name)` case.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, head over to [vi.stackexchange.com](http://vi.stackexchange.com/), maybe they can help.

Comment: I didn't realise that was a thing now, awesome.

Comment: I didn't either, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, I don't know why the things you've tried haven't worked but you can use `g` to perform a normal mode command on lines matchings a pattern.

Your example would be something like:

```
:%g/public function [gs]et/:s/_\(\w\)/\u\1/g
```

Update:

To match only the method names, we can use the fact that there will only be method names before the first `$`, as this looks to be PHP.

To do that, we can use a negative lookbehind, `@<!`:

```
:%g/public function [gs]et/:s/\(\$.\+\)\@<!_\(\w\)/\u\2/g
```

This will look behind `@<!` for any `$` followed by any number of characters and only match `_\(\w\)` if no `$`s are found.

Bonus points(?):

To do this for multiple buffers stick a `bufdo` in front of the `%g`

Comment: My solutions worked if you repeated the command a few times in a row until no more substitutions were being made. Your solution does the trick by entering the command once. Thanks! There is one edge case I forgot to mention, see the above edit.

Comment: As this is quite a specific case, you 'should' be able to use some sort of regex negative look behind to only match before the first `$`. It's not something I use regularly so will take me a little time to make it work, if it does at all.

Answer (score 0):

To have `vi` do replace sad with happy, on all lines, in a file:

`:1, $ s/sad/happy/g`

(It is the `:1, $` before the `sed` command that instructs vi to execute the command on every line in the file.)

Comment: My issue isn't simply to replace every instance of _\(\w\) with \u\1, I want to do this ONLY on lines defining getters and setters and ONLY the function name, not any parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a substitute with an expression (`:h sub-replace-expression`)

Match the complete string you want to process then pass that string to a second substitute command to actually change the string

```
:%s/\(get\|set\)\zs_\w\+/\=substitute(submatch(0), '_\([A-Za-z]\)', '\U\1', 'g')
```

Running the above on

```
get_method_name($variable_name)
set_method_name($variable_name)
```

returns

```
getMethodName($variable_name)
setMethodName($variable_name)
```